# How to use Java API?

Tags: eclipse, api, jar, import

I've been given an online API (just a website that hosts multiple functions and an API to use them. How do I use it? There's no jar file to implement or any other help. All I have is the site with the usable functions (e.g. typing in a countryname and getting back the countrycode) and the API documentation.

I want to be able to use those functions in eclipse. If I've understood correctly I need a jar file to import in eclipse? I'm unable to find a jar file on that website, even though it states that it's a free and easy to use API.

Comment: What is the website?  Does the site expose a REST or SOAP interface?

Comment: This appears to be a REST service.  Please research on how to access a REST service in Java.  Here is a good starting point: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the link of the online API.

Statement is bit confusing. Are you looking at  the API doc or actual API.

If the API is Online it should be REST Service Or the SOAP. If it is API doc then you need to download the libraries of the API and then need to use it.